# How to stop recursion in my bubble sort code when the list is sorted?

Tags: python, sorting, recursion

**Problem**: Implement bubble sort in python. Don’t use Python’s built in sort or sorted. Assume your inputs will be sufficient for the memory you have.

Code :

```
def check_if_sorted(details):
    """compares two consecutive integers in a list and returns the list if sorted else get the list sorted by calling another function"""
    i = 0
    while i <=  len(details) - 2:
        if details[i] < details[i+1]:
            status = True
            i = i+1
            print details
        else:
            bubble_sort(details)
    if status :
        return details


def bubble_sort(details):  
    """compares two consecutive integers in a list and shifts the smaller one to left """
    for i in range(len(details)-1):
        if details[i] > details[i+1]:
            temp = details[i]
            details[i]= details[i+1]
            details[i+1] = temp
    return check_if_sorted(details)


sort_me = [11,127,56,2,1,5,7,9,11,65,12,24,76,87,123,65,8,32,86,123,67,1,67,92,72,39,49,12, 98,52,45,19,37,22,1,66,943,415,21,785,12,698,26,36,18,97,0,63,25,85,24,94,1501]
print sort_me 
print bubble_sort(sort_me)
```

I have written the following code but it keeps on running even after sorting the list and then prints messsage "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object". How can I stop recursion after checking the list is sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need `check_if_sorted(details)` function. use `try/except` in your sort function to check `IndexError` and keep calling the `bubble_sort()` function.

```
def bubble_sort(details):  
    """compares two consecutive integers in a list and shifts the smaller one to left """
    for i in range(len(details)-1):
        try:
            if details[i] > details[i+1]:
                temp = details[i]
                details[i]= details[i+1]
                details[i+1] = temp
                bubble_sort(details)
        except IndexError:
            return
    return details


sort_me = [11,127,56,2,1,5,7,9,11,65,12,24,76,87,123,65,8,32,86,123,67,1,67,92,72,39,49,12, 98,52,45,19,37,22,1,66,943,415,21,785,12,698,26,36,18,97,0,63,25,85,24,94,1501]
print(sort_me)
print(bubble_sort(sort_me))
```

Answer (score 1):

In `check_if_sorted` you do not check for equal.  This causes the duplicates in your list to trigger another (unneeded) calling to `bubble_sort` causing an infinite loop.  To fix it change the comparison line in `check_if_sorted` to:

```
        if details[i] <= details[i+1]:
```

Edit:
This solves the infinite loop, However your algorithm is very inefficient.  To improve your algorithm I suggest a google search for 'bubble sort algorithm', and/or a discussion with your instructor

Comment: That solves the problem of infinite loop but code doesn't stop immediately after sorting  the entire list